# React change footer background from black to a full height image doesnt work

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to change my black bg in the footer without repeat. Cant seem to work?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's on the css of the child's `section` element? it seems like its overlaid on top of your footer, thats why its covering the background on your footer

Comment: you are right, i fixed it . thanks!